# Comparing 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL tables, one contains 2 columns, First Name and Last Name and the other has a column called  NAME which has full names in it. I am trying to find if any of the values from the Last Name column in table1 can be found in the NAME column of table2. So far I have tried the following query without much success:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ('%'+table1.[Last Name]+'%' LIKE table2.NAME)) table2
```

Comment: SQL Server is not the best tool for this, because it has little regex support.  Also, full names can sometimes contain things like suffixes, middle names, etc., so your problem is not yet well defined.  Please at least show us some data.

Comment: Flip the LIKE in your where clause so its "(table2.NAME LIKE '%'+[Last Name]+'%')"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM tabl2 WHERE Name LIKE '%' + table1.LastName + '%'), 0)= 1
```

This query's accuracy can suffer in case of similar first and last names. You can add white spaces for better accuracy: `LIKE '% table1.LastName %'`.